# Why page number in libre writer shown as grey-background text "page numbers"?

Tags: libreoffice

After I clicked `Insert->Fileds-> Page Numbers`, I get a grey-background literal "page numbers" instead of a number. (Environment: LibreOffice 3.5.7.2, Ubuntu 14 LTS.)

[image: grey-background literal "page numbers"]

When I double clicked that grey text "page numbers", `Edit Fields: Document` dialog is opened. I tried style `Arablic(1 2 3)` and `As Page Style`, the problem still exist.

How can I have the real number (e.g, arabic number)?

Comment: Libre version, Ubuntu version, have you made a master page?

Comment: @Tim LibreOffice 3.5.7.2, Ubuntu 14 LTS. There is no master page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an option to toggle between the field value and the field name - in your case, it seems that LO is displaying the field name instead of the field value. You can change it on different, alternative  ways:

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>;
- Menu "`View`" -> "`Field Names`";
- Menu "`Tools`" -> "`Options`" -> "`LibreOffice Writer`" -> "`View`" -> disable "`Field Codes`".

*(tested with LO 4.2.6.3 and Ubuntu 14.04 LTS)*

Comment: Yep - right answer!

Answer (score 1):

The gray background is simply there to denote a field. This background is not printed. Choose View > Field Shadings (or press Ctrl+F8) to turn this feature off.